# Task scheduling iOS

Tags: ios, scheduled-tasks, alarm

I want to develop an **iOS application** where my application can run certain task at certain instance of time.

**For example:**
The user will launch my application and set the task launch time to 5:00 pm. Then at 5 pm, my application should start the task XYZ even without launching my application (that task can run in background without user intervention).

I am looking for some help to figure out which **iOS frameworks** can help to **schedule tasks**?

Answer (score 1):

We can't schedule a task in iOS. For this you have to move on different approach. You have to use NSNotification to achieve your goal.

You can follow this url for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32248870/2846524

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you refer any sample iOS code base with similar functionality?